# Pandas - formatting a NxN matrix

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe

I have to deal with a square matrix (N x N) (N will change depending on the system, but the matrix will always be a square matrix).

Here is an example:

```
                    0                  1                  2                  3                  4        
    0     5.1677124550E-001  5.4962112499E-005  3.2484393256E-002 -1.8901697652E-001 -6.7156804753E-003
    1     5.5380106796E-005  5.6159927753E-001 -1.9000545049E-003 -1.4737748792E-002 -7.2598453774E-002
    2     3.2486915835E-002 -1.8996351539E-003  5.6791783316E-001  7.2316374186E-002  1.5013066446E-003
    3    -1.8901411495E-001 -1.4737367075E-002  7.2315825338E-002  6.2721160365E-001  3.1553528602E-002
    4    -6.7136454124E-003 -7.2597907350E-002  1.5007743348E-003  3.1554372311E-002  2.7318109331E-001
    5     6.6738948243E-002  1.4102132238E-003 -1.2689244944E-001  4.7666038803E-002  1.8559074897E-002
    6    -2.5293332676E-002  3.7536452002E-002 -1.3453018251E-002 -1.3177136905E-001  6.8262612506E-002
    7     5.0951492945E-003  2.1082303893E-005  2.2599127408E-004  1.0287898189E-001 -1.1117916184E-001
    8     1.0818230191E-003 -1.2435319909E-002  8.1008075834E-003 -4.2864102001E-002  4.2865913226E-002
    9    -1.8399671295E-002 -2.1579653853E-002 -8.3073582356E-003 -2.1848513510E-001 -7.3408914625E-002
   10     3.4566032399E-003 -4.0687639382E-003  1.3769999130E-003 -1.1873434189E-001 -3.3274201039E-002
   11     6.6093238125E-003  1.7153435473E-002  4.9392012712E-003 -8.4590814134E-002 -4.3601041176E-002
   12    -1.1418316960E-001 -1.1241625427E-001 -3.2263873516E-002 -1.9323129435E-002 -2.6233049625E-002
   13    -1.1352899039E-001 -2.2898299860E-001 -5.3035072561E-002  7.4480651562E-004  6.3778892206E-004
   14    -3.2197359289E-002 -5.3404040557E-002 -6.2530142462E-002  9.6648204015E-003  1.5382174347E-002
   15    -1.2210509335E-001  1.1380412205E-001 -3.8374895516E-002 -1.2823165326E-002  2.3865200517E-002
   16     1.1478157080E-001 -2.1487971631E-001  5.9955334103E-002 -1.2803721235E-003 -2.2477259002E-004
   17    -3.9162044498E-002  6.0167325377E-002 -6.7692892326E-002  6.3814569032E-003 -1.3309923267E-002
   18    -5.1386866211E-002 -1.1483215267E-003 -3.8482481829E-002  2.2227734790E-003  2.4860195290E-004
   19    -1.8287048910E-003 -4.5442287955E-002 -7.6787332291E-003  7.6970470456E-004 -1.8456603178E-003
   20    -3.4812676792E-002 -7.8376169613E-003 -3.1205975353E-001 -2.8005140005E-003  3.9792109835E-004
   21     2.6908361866E-003  3.7102890907E-004  2.8494060446E-002 -4.8904422930E-002 -5.8840348122E-004
   22    -1.6354677061E-003  2.2592828188E-003  1.6591434361E-004 -4.9992263663E-003 -4.3243295112E-002
   23    -1.4297833794E-003 -1.7830154308E-003 -1.1426700328E-002  1.7125095395E-003 -1.2016863398E-002
   24     1.6271802154E-003  1.6383303957E-003 -7.8049656555E-004  3.7177399735E-003 -1.0472268655E-002
   25    -4.1949740427E-004  1.5301971185E-004 -9.8681335931E-004 -2.2257204483E-004 -5.1722898203E-003
   26     1.0290471110E-003  9.3255502541E-004  7.7166886713E-004  4.5630851485E-003 -4.3761358485E-003
   27    -7.0031784470E-004 -3.5205332654E-003 -1.6311730073E-003 -1.2805479632E-002 -6.5565487971E-003
   28     7.4046927792E-004  1.9332629981E-003  3.7374682636E-004  3.9965654817E-003 -6.2275912806E-003
   29    -3.4680278867E-004 -2.3027344089E-003 -1.1338817043E-003 -1.2023581780E-002 -5.4242202971E-003
                    5                  6                  7                  8                  9        
    0     6.6743285428E-002 -2.5292337123E-002  5.0949675928E-003  1.0817408844E-003 -1.8399704662E-002
    1     1.4100215877E-003  3.7536256943E-002  2.1212526899E-005 -1.2435482773E-002 -2.1579384876E-002
    2    -1.2689432485E-001 -1.3453164785E-002  2.2618690004E-004  8.1008703937E-003 -8.3084039605E-003
    3     4.7663851818E-002 -1.3181118094E-001  1.0290976691E-001 -4.2887391630E-002 -2.1847562123E-001
    4     1.8558453001E-002  6.8311145594E-002 -1.1122358467E-001  4.2891711956E-002 -7.3413776745E-002
    5     6.5246209445E-001 -3.7960754525E-002  5.8439215647E-002 -9.0620367134E-002 -8.4164313206E-002
    6    -3.7935271881E-002  1.9415336793E-001 -6.8115262349E-002  5.0899890760E-002 -3.3687874555E-002
    7     5.8422477033E-002 -6.8128901087E-002  3.9950499633E-001 -4.4336879147E-002 -4.0665928103E-002
    8    -9.0612201567E-002  5.0902528870E-002 -4.4330072001E-002  1.2680415316E-001  1.7096405711E-002
    9    -8.4167028549E-002 -3.3690056890E-002 -4.0677875424E-002  1.7097273427E-002  5.2579065978E-001
   10    -6.4841142152E-002 -5.4453858464E-003 -2.4697277476E-001  8.5069643903E-005  1.8744016178E-001
   11    -1.0367060076E-001  1.5864203200E-002 -1.6074822795E-002 -5.5265410413E-002 -7.3152548403E-002
   12    -9.0665723957E-003  3.3027526012E-003  1.8484849938E-003 -7.5841163489E-004 -3.3700244298E-003
   13     4.7717318460E-004 -1.8118719766E-003  1.6014630540E-003 -2.3830908057E-004  2.1049292570E-003
   14     4.3836856576E-003 -1.7242302777E-003 -1.2023546553E-003  4.0533783460E-004  1.4850814596E-003
   15    -1.2402059167E-002 -7.4793143461E-003 -3.8769252328E-004  3.9551076185E-003  1.0737706641E-003
   16    -9.3076805579E-005 -1.6074185601E-003  1.7551579833E-003 -5.1663470094E-004  1.1072804383E-003
   17     4.6817349747E-003  3.6900011954E-003 -8.6155331565E-004 -9.1007768778E-005 -7.3899260162E-004
   18     3.2959550689E-002  3.0400921147E-003  3.9724187499E-004 -1.9220339108E-003  1.8075790317E-003
   19     7.0905456379E-004 -5.0949208181E-004 -4.6021500516E-004 -7.9847500945E-004  1.4079850530E-004
   20    -1.8687467448E-002 -6.3913023759E-004 -7.3566296037E-004  2.3726543730E-003 -1.0663719038E-003
   21     3.6598966411E-003 -8.2335128379E-003  7.5645765132E-004 -2.1824880567E-002 -3.5125687811E-003
   22    -1.6198130808E-002  8.4576317115E-003 -6.2045498682E-004  3.3460766491E-002  3.2638760335E-003
   23    -3.2057393808E-001 -1.1315081941E-002  3.4822885510E-003 -5.8263446092E-003  2.9508421818E-004
   24    -2.6366856593E-002 -5.8331954255E-004  1.1995976399E-003  3.4813904521E-003 -5.0942740761E-002
   25     6.5474742063E-003 -5.7681583908E-003 -2.2680039574E-002 -3.3264360995E-002  4.8925407218E-003
   26    -1.1288074542E-002 -4.5938216710E-003 -1.9339903561E-003  1.0812058656E-002  2.3005958417E-002
   27     1.8937006089E-002  6.5590668002E-003 -2.9973042787E-003 -9.1466195902E-003 -2.0027029530E-001
   28    -5.0006834397E-003 -3.1011487603E-002 -2.1071980031E-002  1.5171078954E-002 -6.3286786806E-002
   29     1.0199591553E-002 -7.9372677248E-004  3.0157129340E-003  3.3043947441E-003  1.2554933598E-001
                   10                 11                 12                 13                 14        
    0     3.4566170422E-003  6.6091516193E-003 -1.1418209846E-001 -1.1352717720E-001 -3.2196213169E-002
    1    -4.0687114857E-003  1.7153538295E-002 -1.1241515840E-001 -2.2897846552E-001 -5.3401852861E-002
    2     1.3767476381E-003  4.9395834885E-003 -3.2262805417E-002 -5.3032729716E-002 -6.2527093260E-002
    3    -1.1874067860E-001 -8.4586993618E-002 -1.9322697616E-002  7.4504831410E-004  9.6646936748E-003
    4    -3.3280804952E-002 -4.3604931512E-002 -2.6232842935E-002  6.3789697287E-004  1.5382093474E-002
    5    -6.4845769217E-002 -1.0366990398E-001 -9.0664935892E-003  4.7719667654E-004  4.3835884630E-003
    6    -5.4306282394E-003  1.5863464756E-002  3.3027917727E-003 -1.8118646089E-003 -1.7242102753E-003
    7    -2.4687457565E-001 -1.6075394559E-002  1.8484728466E-003  1.6014634135E-003 -1.2023496466E-003
    8     8.5962912652E-005 -5.5265657567E-002 -7.5843145596E-004 -2.3831274033E-004  4.0533385644E-004
    9     1.8744386918E-001 -7.3152643002E-002 -3.3700964189E-003  2.1048865009E-003  1.4850822567E-003
   10     4.2975054072E-001  1.0364270794E-001 -1.5875283846E-003  6.7147216913E-004  1.2875627684E-004
   11     1.0364402707E-001  6.0712435750E-001  5.1492123223E-003  8.2705404716E-004 -1.8653698814E-003
   12    -1.5875318643E-003  5.1492269487E-003  1.2662026379E-001  1.2488481495E-001  3.3008712754E-002
   13     6.7147489686E-004  8.2705994225E-004  1.2488477299E-001  2.4603749137E-001  5.7666439818E-002
   14     1.2875157882E-004 -1.8653719810E-003  3.3008614344E-002  5.7666322609E-002  6.3196096154E-002
   15     1.1375173141E-003 -1.2188735107E-003  9.5708352328E-003 -1.3282223067E-002  5.3571128896E-003
   16     2.1319373893E-004 -2.6367828437E-004  1.4833724552E-002 -2.0115235494E-002  7.8461850894E-003
   17     2.3051283757E-004  3.4044831571E-004  4.9262824289E-003 -6.6151918659E-003  1.1684894610E-003
   18    -5.6658408835E-004  1.5710333316E-003 -2.6543076573E-003  1.0490950154E-003 -1.5676208892E-002
   19     1.0005496308E-003  1.0400419914E-003 -2.7122935995E-003 -5.3716049248E-005 -2.6747366947E-002
   20     3.1068907684E-004  5.3348953665E-004 -4.7934824223E-004  4.4853558686E-004 -6.0300656596E-003
   21     2.7080517882E-003 -1.9033626829E-002  8.8615570289E-004 -3.7735646663E-004 -7.4101143501E-004
   22    -2.9622921796E-003 -2.4159082408E-002  6.6943323966E-004  1.1154593780E-004  1.5914682394E-004
   23     3.2842560830E-003 -6.2612752482E-003  1.5738434272E-004  4.6284599959E-004  4.0588132107E-004
   24     1.6971737369E-003  2.4217812563E-002  4.3246402884E-004  9.5059931011E-005  3.5484698283E-004
   25    -7.4868993750E-002 -8.7332668698E-002 -6.0147742690E-005 -4.8099146029E-005  1.1509155506E-004
   26    -9.3177706949E-002 -2.9315061874E-001  2.1287190612E-004  5.0813661565E-005  2.6955715462E-004
   27    -7.0097859908E-002  1.2458191360E-001 -1.2846480258E-003  1.2192486380E-004  4.6853704861E-004
   28    -6.9485493530E-002  4.8763866344E-002  7.7223643475E-004  1.3853535883E-004  5.4636752811E-005
   29     4.8961381968E-002 -1.5272337445E-001 -8.8648769643E-004 -4.4975303480E-005  5.9586006091E-004
                   15                 16                 17                 18                 19        
    0    -1.2210501176E-001  1.1478027359E-001 -3.9162145749E-002 -5.1389252158E-002 -1.8288904037E-003
    1     1.1380272374E-001 -2.1487588526E-001  6.0165774430E-002 -1.1487007778E-003 -4.5441546655E-002
    2    -3.8374694597E-002  5.9953296524E-002 -6.7691825286E-002 -3.8484030260E-002 -7.6800715249E-003
    3    -1.2822729286E-002 -1.2805898275E-003  6.3813065178E-003  2.2220841872E-003  7.6991955181E-004
    4     2.3864994996E-002 -2.2470892452E-004 -1.3309838494E-002  2.4851560674E-004 -1.8460620529E-003
    5    -1.2402212045E-002 -9.2994801153E-005  4.6817064931E-003  3.2958166488E-002  7.0866732024E-004
    6    -7.4793278406E-003 -1.6074103229E-003  3.6899979002E-003  3.0392561951E-003 -5.0946020505E-004
    7    -3.8770026733E-004  1.7551659565E-003 -8.6155605026E-004  3.9692465089E-004 -4.6038088334E-004
    8     3.9551171890E-003 -5.1663991899E-004 -9.1008948343E-005 -1.9220277566E-003 -7.9837924658E-004
    9     1.0738350084E-003  1.1072790098E-003 -7.3897453645E-004  1.8057852560E-003  1.4013275714E-004
   10     1.1375075076E-003  2.1317640112E-004  2.3050639764E-004 -5.6673414945E-004  1.0005316579E-003
   11    -1.2189105982E-003 -2.6367792495E-004  3.4043235164E-004  1.5732522246E-003  1.0407973658E-003
   12     9.5708232459E-003  1.4833737759E-002  4.9262816092E-003 -2.6542614308E-003 -2.7122986789E-003
   13    -1.3282260152E-002 -2.0115238348E-002 -6.6152067653E-003  1.0491248568E-003 -5.3705750675E-005
   14     5.3571028398E-003  7.8462085672E-003  1.1684872139E-003 -1.5676176683E-002 -2.6747374282E-002
   15     1.3378635756E-001 -1.2613361119E-001  4.2401828623E-002 -2.6595403473E-003  1.9873360401E-003
   16    -1.2613349126E-001  2.3154756121E-001 -6.5778628114E-002 -2.2828335280E-003  1.4601821131E-003
   17     4.2401749392E-002 -6.5778591727E-002  6.8187241643E-002 -1.6653902450E-002  2.5505038138E-002
   18    -2.6595920073E-003 -2.2828074980E-003 -1.6653942562E-002  5.4855247002E-002  2.4729783529E-003
   19     1.9873415121E-003  1.4601899329E-003  2.5505058190E-002  2.4729967206E-003  4.4724663284E-002
   20    -3.8366743828E-004 -8.8746730931E-004 -6.4420927497E-003  3.6656962180E-002  8.1224860664E-003
   21     9.2845385141E-004  3.6802433505E-004 -9.5040708316E-004 -5.1941208846E-003 -1.2444625713E-004
   22    -5.0318487549E-004  1.4342911215E-004  2.8985859503E-004  2.0416113478E-004  9.1951318240E-004
   23     7.4036073171E-004 -3.4730013615E-004 -1.3351566400E-004  2.3474188588E-003  1.3102362758E-005
   24    -2.7749145090E-004  4.7724454321E-005  5.5527644806E-005 -1.7302886151E-004 -1.7726879169E-004
   25    -2.5090250470E-004  2.1741519930E-005  2.7208805916E-004 -2.5982303487E-004 -1.9668228900E-004
   26    -1.4489113997E-004 -3.0397727583E-005  2.7239543481E-005 -6.0050637375E-004 -2.9892198193E-005
   27    -1.6519482597E-005  1.6435294198E-004  5.0961893634E-005  1.4077278097E-004 -1.9027010603E-005
   28    -2.3547595249E-004  7.6124571826E-005  1.0117983985E-004 -1.1534040559E-004 -1.0579685787E-004
   29     7.0507166233E-005  1.1552377841E-004 -4.5931305760E-005 -2.0007797315E-004 -1.3505340062E-004
                   20                 21                 22                 23                 24        
    0    -3.4812101478E-002  2.6911592086E-003 -1.6354152863E-003 -1.4301333227E-003  1.6249964844E-003
    1    -7.8382610347E-003  3.7103408229E-004  2.2593110441E-003 -1.7829862164E-003  1.6374435740E-003
    2    -3.1205423941E-001  2.8493671639E-002  1.6587990556E-004 -1.1426237591E-002 -7.8189111866E-004
    3    -2.8004725758E-003 -4.8903739721E-002 -4.9988134121E-003  1.7100983514E-003  3.7179545055E-003
    4     3.9806443322E-004 -5.8790208912E-004 -4.3242458298E-002 -1.2016207108E-002 -1.0472139534E-002
    5    -1.8686790048E-002  3.6592865292E-003 -1.6198931842E-002 -3.2057224847E-001 -2.6367531700E-002
    6    -6.3919412091E-004 -8.2335246704E-003  8.4576155591E-003 -1.1315054733E-002 -5.8369163532E-004
    7    -7.3581915791E-004  7.5646519519E-004 -6.2047477465E-004  3.4823216513E-003  1.1991380964E-003
    8     2.3726528036E-003 -2.1824763131E-002  3.3460717579E-002 -5.8262172949E-003  3.4812921433E-003
    9    -1.0665296285E-003 -3.5124206435E-003  3.2639684654E-003  2.9530797749E-004 -5.0943824872E-002
   10     3.1067613876E-004  2.7079189356E-003 -2.9623459983E-003  3.2841200274E-003  1.6984442797E-003
   11     5.3351732140E-004 -1.9033427571E-002 -2.4158940046E-002 -6.2609613281E-003  2.4221378111E-002
   12    -4.7937892256E-004  8.8611314755E-004  6.6939922854E-004  1.5740024716E-004  4.3249394082E-004
   13     4.4851926804E-004 -3.7736678097E-004  1.1153694999E-004  4.6284806253E-004  9.5077824774E-005
   14    -6.0300787410E-003 -7.4096053004E-004  1.5918637627E-004  4.0586523098E-004  3.5485782222E-004
   15    -3.8368712363E-004  9.2843754228E-004 -5.0316845184E-004  7.4036906127E-004 -2.7745851356E-004
   16    -8.8745240886E-004  3.6801936222E-004  1.4342995270E-004 -3.4729860789E-004  4.7711904531E-005
   17    -6.4420819427E-003 -9.5038506002E-004  2.8983698019E-004 -1.3352326563E-004  5.5544671478E-005
   18     3.6656852373E-002 -5.1941195232E-003  2.0415783452E-004  2.3474119607E-003 -1.7153048632E-004
   19     8.1224361521E-003 -1.2444681834E-004  9.1951236579E-004  1.3097434442E-005 -1.7668019335E-004
   20     3.3911554853E-001  2.8652507893E-003 -6.8339696880E-005  3.7476484447E-004  8.3606654277E-004
   21     2.8652527558E-003  6.1967615286E-002 -3.2455918220E-003  7.8074203872E-003 -1.5351890960E-003
   22    -6.8340068690E-005 -3.2455946984E-003  4.1826230856E-002  6.5337193429E-003 -3.1932674182E-003
   23     3.7476336333E-004  7.8073802579E-003  6.5336763366E-003  3.4246747567E-001 -2.2590437719E-005
   24     8.3515185725E-004 -1.5351889308E-003 -3.1932682244E-003 -2.2585651674E-005  4.7006835231E-002
   25     5.3158843621E-007  1.0652535047E-003  1.4954902777E-003  2.4073368793E-004  1.1954474977E-003
   26     5.5963948637E-004 -4.4872582333E-004 -1.4772351943E-003  6.3199701928E-004 -2.1389718034E-002
   27    -1.7619372799E-004  9.0741766644E-004  9.8175835796E-004 -2.9459682310E-004  7.2835611826E-004
   28     2.5127782091E-004 -9.3298199434E-004  6.8787235133E-005  1.2732690365E-004  7.9688727422E-003
   29     2.6201943695E-004  1.7128017387E-004  1.2934748675E-003  3.4008367645E-004  1.9615268308E-002
                   25                 26                 27                 28                 29        
    0    -4.2035299977E-004  1.0294528397E-003 -7.0032537135E-004  7.4047266192E-004 -3.4678947810E-004
    1     1.5264932827E-004  9.3263518942E-004 -3.5205362458E-003  1.9332600101E-003 -2.3027335108E-003
    2    -9.8735571502E-004  7.7177183895E-004 -1.6311830663E-003  3.7374078263E-004 -1.1338849320E-003
    3    -2.2267753982E-004  4.5631164845E-003 -1.2805227755E-002  3.9967067646E-003 -1.2023590679E-002
    4    -5.1722782688E-003 -4.3757731112E-003 -6.5561880794E-003 -6.2274289617E-003 -5.4242286711E-003
    5     6.5472637324E-003 -1.1287788747E-002  1.8937046693E-002 -5.0006811267E-003  1.0199602824E-002
    6    -5.7685226078E-003 -4.5935456207E-003  6.5591405092E-003 -3.1011377655E-002 -7.9382348181E-004
    7    -2.2680665405E-002 -1.9338350120E-003 -2.9972765688E-003 -2.1071947728E-002  3.0156847654E-003
    8    -3.3264515239E-002  1.0812126530E-002 -9.1466888768E-003  1.5170890552E-002  3.3044094214E-003
    9     4.8928775025E-003  2.3007654009E-002 -2.0026482543E-001 -6.3285758846E-002  1.2554808336E-001
   10    -7.4869041758E-002 -9.3178724533E-002 -7.0098856149E-002 -6.9485640501E-002  4.8962839723E-002
   11    -8.7330564494E-002 -2.9314613543E-001  1.2458021507E-001  4.8763534298E-002 -1.5272144228E-001
   12    -6.0132426168E-005  2.1286995818E-004 -1.2846479090E-003  7.7223667108E-004 -8.8648784383E-004
   13    -4.8090893023E-005  5.0813447259E-005  1.2192474211E-004  1.3853537972E-004 -4.4975512069E-005
   14     1.1509828375E-004  2.6955725919E-004  4.6853708025E-004  5.4636589826E-005  5.9585997916E-004
   15    -2.5088560837E-004 -1.4490239429E-004 -1.6517113547E-005 -2.3547725232E-004  7.0506301073E-005
   16     2.1741623849E-005 -3.0396484786E-005  1.6435437640E-004  7.6123660238E-005  1.1552303684E-004
   17     2.7209709129E-004  2.7234932342E-005  5.0963084246E-005  1.0117936124E-004 -4.5931984725E-005
   18    -2.5882735848E-004 -6.0031848430E-004  1.4070861538E-004 -1.1535910049E-004 -2.0001808065E-004
   19    -1.9638025822E-004 -2.9919459983E-005 -1.9047914816E-005 -1.0580143635E-004 -1.3503643634E-004
   20     8.4829116415E-007  5.5948891149E-004 -1.7619563318E-004  2.5127749619E-004  2.6202088722E-004
   21     1.0652521780E-003 -4.4872868033E-004  9.0739586785E-004 -9.3299673048E-004  1.7126146660E-004
   22     1.4954902653E-003 -1.4772362211E-003  9.8175151528E-004  6.8801505444E-005  1.2934673074E-003
   23     2.4072903510E-004  6.3199689136E-004 -2.9460500091E-004  1.2731327319E-004  3.4007600115E-004
   24     1.1952923145E-003 -2.1389995888E-002  7.2832026293E-004  7.9688600183E-003  1.9615297182E-002
   25     9.4289717269E-002  1.0562741426E-001 -1.7552990896E-004  7.0060843371E-003  8.7782610441E-003
   26     1.0562750999E-001  3.0308674016E-001 -1.6382699707E-003 -5.5832273099E-003 -1.1726448645E-002
   27    -1.7551353029E-004 -1.6382784849E-003  2.0673701256E-001  8.2101212014E-002 -1.3115219203E-001
   28     7.0060896795E-003 -5.5832572276E-003  8.2101377926E-002  8.7668224780E-002 -5.4259499038E-002
   29     8.7782416309E-003 -1.1726450275E-002 -1.3115216547E-001 -5.4259354736E-002  1.5092602943E-001
```

This should be a 30x30 matrix and I'm trying:

```
data = pd.read_fwf('C:/Users/henri/Documents/Projects/Python-Lessons/ORCA/orca.hess',
                   widths=[9, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19])
```

But it reads as 185x6. I'd like to ignore the first column (numbering the lines) from 0-29 and I'm not using the columns indexes (from 0-29 too) to perform any mathematical operation. Also, Pandas is rounding my numbers and I'd like to keep the original format.

Here is a snip of my output:

```
     Unnamed: 0             0         1         2         3         4
0           0.0  5.167712e-01  0.000055  0.032484 -0.189017 -0.006716
1           1.0  5.538011e-05  0.561599 -0.001900 -0.014738 -0.072598
2           2.0  3.248692e-02 -0.001900  0.567918  0.072316  0.001501
```

Any help is much appreciated, guys.

Comment: Does your csv file look like this, with the columns on top of one another?

Comment: Yes, it does! This is a hessian matrix generated by a quantum chemistry software.

Comment: Unfortunately you're going to have a hard time parsing this with pandas.... columns need to be next to each other, not one below the other.

Comment: I'm open to other methods too (if any available). :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'data'
df = pd.read_fwf(filename, widths=[9, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19])
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'row'})
df = df.dropna(subset=['row'], how='any')
df['col'] = df.groupby('row').cumcount()
df = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col')
df = df.dropna(how='any', axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
print(df.head())
```

yields

```
           0         1         2         3         4         5         6   \
row                                                                         
0.0  0.516771  0.066743  0.003457 -0.122105 -0.034812 -0.000420  0.000055   
1.0  0.000055  0.001410 -0.004069  0.113803 -0.007838  0.000153  0.561599   
2.0  0.032487 -0.126894  0.001377 -0.038375 -0.312054 -0.000987 -0.001900   
3.0 -0.189014  0.047664 -0.118741 -0.012823 -0.002800 -0.000223 -0.014737   
4.0 -0.006714  0.018558 -0.033281  0.023865  0.000398 -0.005172 -0.072598   

           7         8         9     ...           20        21        22  \
row                                  ...                                    
0.0 -0.025292  0.006609  0.114780    ...    -0.113527 -0.051389 -0.001430   
1.0  0.037536  0.017154 -0.214876    ...    -0.228978 -0.001149 -0.001783   
2.0 -0.013453  0.004940  0.059953    ...    -0.053033 -0.038484 -0.011426   
3.0 -0.131811 -0.084587 -0.001281    ...     0.000745  0.002222  0.001710   
4.0  0.068311 -0.043605 -0.000225    ...     0.000638  0.000249 -0.012016   

           23        24        25        26        27        28        29  
row                                                                        
0.0  0.000740 -0.006716 -0.018400 -0.032196 -0.001829  0.001625 -0.000347  
1.0  0.001933 -0.072598 -0.021579 -0.053402 -0.045442  0.001637 -0.002303  
2.0  0.000374  0.001501 -0.008308 -0.062527 -0.007680 -0.000782 -0.001134  
3.0  0.003997  0.031554 -0.218476  0.009665  0.000770  0.003718 -0.012024  
4.0 -0.006227  0.273181 -0.073414  0.015382 -0.001846 -0.010472 -0.005424  

[5 rows x 30 columns]
```

---

After parsing the file with

```
df = pd.read_fwf(filename, widths=[9, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19])
df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'row'})
```

the column headers can be identified by have a `df['row']` value of `NaN`.
So they can be removed with

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['row'], how='any')
```

Now the `row` numbers keep repeating from 0 to 29. If we group by the `row`
value, then we can assign an intra-group "cumulative count" to the rows within
each group.  That is, the first row of the group gets assigned the value 0, the
next row 1, etc. -- within that group -- and the process is repeated for each
group.

```
df['col'] = df.groupby('row').cumcount()

#       row             0         1         2         3         4  col
# 0     0.0  5.167712e-01  0.000055  0.032484 -0.189017 -0.006716    0
# 1     1.0  5.538011e-05  0.561599 -0.001900 -0.014738 -0.072598    0
# 2     2.0  3.248692e-02 -0.001900  0.567918  0.072316  0.001501    0
# ...
# 182  27.0 -1.755135e-04 -0.001638  0.206737  0.082101 -0.131152    5
# 183  28.0  7.006090e-03 -0.005583  0.082101  0.087668 -0.054259    5
# 184  29.0  8.778242e-03 -0.011726 -0.131152 -0.054259  0.150926    5
```

Now the desired DataFrame can be obtained by pivoting:

```
df = df.pivot(index='row', columns='col')
```

and relabeling the columns:

```
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

---

A more NumPy-based approach might look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
filename = 'data'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace=True)
arr = df.values
N = df.index.max()+1
arr = np.delete(arr, np.arange(N, len(arr), N+1), axis=0)
chunks = np.split(arr, np.arange(N, len(arr), N))
result = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(chunks)).dropna(axis=1)
print(result)
```

This will also work for any sized matrix.

Comment: Dear @unutbu, can that be dynamically expanded to a 30x30 matrix? Some times the matrix will be larger, sometimes smaller (but always with the equal number of lines and columns 200x200, 15x15 etc), so, parsing the data looks like a very hard task.

Comment: The only line that uses hardcoded numbers is the `width` parameter. Everything else will work fine for any matrix (even non-square ones).

Comment: Do you know in advance the shape of the desired matrix when you read the file? If you do, then it would not be hard to generate the appropriate `width` list to parse the file.

Comment: Yes! That's great! Thank you, @unutbu!
Is it normal that the numbers are rounded from the scientific notation? Is there any way to keep the original format to keep precision?

Comment: The size depends on the size of the molecule, but it will always be 3 x (Number of atoms). (So, this molecule have 10 atoms)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to address that -- Pandas formats the DataFrame with a default precision for floats which makes it appear as though the float has been rounded, when in fact the full float is actually still intact. (This is assuming that the string-floats in the file can be successfully parsed as Python floats.)

Comment: "in fact the full float is actually still intact". That is a relief. I can not thank you enough. Thanks for using your time to give me a hand here.

Comment: @unutbu is there any particular reason behind doing all these complicated operations when you could just retile based on index?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: The particular reason is that it was the first method that occurred to me :) However, you might want to try your code on different sized data file. With a 27x27 matrix, it appears your current code returns a DataFrame of shape (27, 25), but that's probably repairable...

Comment: @unutbu Fair enough! I'll fix that as soon as I get home. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @unutbu I just realised that my method will not work when the the rows have been presented in a form M X N' where N' does not divide N. In the example above, N' is 5 (columns) and 5 divides 30. So, in the last row of columns, you won't have any incomplete columns. In the case where N is 27 and N' is 5, the last row will only have 2 columns, so it is loaded as NaN and dropped. Will add this disclaimer in my answer (I upvoted your answer because it doesn't have this limitation).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: The column divisibility issue can be avoided by passing a list of indices  instead of a number of chunks as the second argument to `np.vsplit`. I've edited my post above to show what I mean.

Comment: @unutbu That's neat! I'll leave my answer as is, since I don't want to copy you.